# Synology can't use second disk

Tags: hard-drive, nas

I got new Synology NAS server with 2 HDD. First one is 2 TB and second 6 TB. It automatically set everything and I just created user. Then I logged in and noticed that I can store my data only to the 2TB HDD. But when I take a look at disk group I can see the second HDD.

Any ideas why I can't use the second 6TB HDD?

[volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akXI9.png)

[disk group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o64S.png)

Comment: Are you asking the reason your capacity didn't go up?

Comment: How is your storage configured. It may be that the Synology's storage setup is focused on data protection, and so you are limited to the size of your smallest drive. I suggest you read up on your Synology and NAS data storage setups and their purposes, strengths, and weaknesses.

Comment: Yes... why it didn't go up when I have 6TB disk + 2TB disk. I guess maybe the problem is RAID?
data protection... you mean RAID?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those that got the same problem... to solve that, I had to backup all my data and then delete the volume. Then create new volume for 2 TB and 6 TB without RAID.